# Удваивание вывода при простом парсинге csv в C++

Tags: c++, csv, парсер

Я написал этот код, и я не могу понять, почему он удваивает строку, когда я компилирую и запускаю ее ...

data.csv состоит из:
0, person, 8, 12, 344, 486

Пожалуйста, скажите мне, почему это происходит и что я могу сделать, чтобы избежать этого.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]. 
Спасибо за любую помощь.

Вот код:

```
ifstream myfile("data.csv");

if(!myfile.is_open()) cout<<"error";

        string num1;
        string num2;
        string num3;
        string num4;
        string num5;
        string num6;

            while(myfile.good()){

                    getline(myfile,num1,',');
                    getline(myfile,num2,',');
                    getline(myfile,num3,',');
                    getline(myfile,num4,',');
                    getline(myfile,num5,',');
                    getline(myfile,num6,'\n');

                    cout<<num1<<","<<num2<<","<<num3<<","<<num4<<","<<num5<<","<<num6<<"\n";
            }

myfile.close();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: На ruSO публикуйте вопросы только на русском языке

Comment: [Разъясните нам](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5872/176217), в чем причина публикации вопроса на английском.

Answer (score 3):

Это происходит из-за того, что после чтения первой строки поток myfile все еще имеет состояние good (ибо неудачных попыток чтения еще не было). На второй итерации цикла, num1 принимает пустое значение, а в потоке встречается конец файла. Остальные num уже не читаются, и сохраняют считанные на первой итерации цикла значения. Предлагаю такую модификацию кода:

```
for(;;)
{
    getline(myfile,num1,',');
    getline(myfile,num2,',');
    getline(myfile,num3,',');
    getline(myfile,num4,',');
    getline(myfile,num5,',');
    getline(myfile,num6,'\n');

    if(myfile.good())
        cout<<num1<<","<<num2<<","<<num3<<","<<num4<<","<<num5<<","<<num6<<"\n";
    else
        break;
}
```

Comment: Даже если вопрос на английском, всё равно надо отвечать на русском!